# Vuetify validation using Model or Controller

Tags: php, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm just trying to add validation in my vuetify form from my Model or Controller and make an alert.

In my `.vue` file

```html
<v-row dense>
    <v-col cols="3">
        <v-text-field dense outlined label="Employee Code" v-model="emp_code"></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="3">
        <v-text-field dense outlined label="Employee Name" v-model="emp_name"></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="2">
        <v-text-field dense outlined label="Age" v-model="emp_age"></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="2">
        <v-btn @click="Insert()">Insert</v-btn>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image]

In my script, I have this data

```js
data: () => ({
    emp_code:null,
    emp_name:null,
    emp_age:null,
}),
```

And my methods is:

```js
methods: {
    Insert(){
        axios.post('api/employees', {
                emp_code:this.emp_code,
                emp_name:this.emp_name,
                emp_age:this.emp_age
            })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data)
            this.emp_code = null
            this.emp_name = null
            this.emp_age = null
        })
    }
}
```

`Controller.php`:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $employee_data = $request->all();
        $employee_code = "12345";
        $employee_model = new EmployeeModel();
        DB::transaction(function() use($employee_model, $employee_data, $employee_code){
            $employee_model->InsertEmployee($employee_data, $employee_code);
        });
    }
```

I'm using DAO and DTO, so

`Model.php`:

```php
public function InsertEmployee($employee_data, $employee_code){
    $employee_data['EmployeeCode'] = $employee_data['emp_code'];
    $employee_data['EmployeeName'] = $employee_data['emp_name'];
    $employee_data['Age'] = $employee_data['emp_age'];
    $employee_data['UpdatedBy'] = $employee_code;
    $dao_insert_employee = new DAO();
    $dao_insert_employee->InsertEmployee($employee_data, $employee_code);
```

`DAO.php`

```php
public static function InsertEmployee($employee_data, $employee_code){
    DB::transaction(function() use($employee_data, $employee_code){
        Employee::insert(
            [
                'EmployeeCode' => $employee_data["emp_code"],
                'EmployeeName' => $employee_data["emp_name"],
                'Age' => $employee_data["emp_age"],
                'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'deleted_at' => null,
                'UpdatedBy' => $employee_code,
            ]
        );
    });
}
```

`DTO.php`

```php
class DTO{
    public $EmployeeCode;
    public $EmployeeName;
    public $Age;
    public $deleted_at;

    /**
     * Get the value of EmployeeCode
     */ 
    public function getEmployeeCode()
    {
        return $this->EmployeeCode;
    }
    public function setEmployeeCode($EmployeeCode)
    {
        $this->EmployeeCode = $EmployeeCode;

        return $this;
    }
//Other codes here...
```

For now, I am able to insert data in my database, But I want to add a validator. I just want a simple alert in no data inputted on the `TextField`:

[image]

And I also want to validate the `employee_code` to it's maxlength to 5 digit only, so if inputted data is 4 digit below or 6digit above, alert will show message like "Employee Code is 5 digit only".

- I'm trying not to have a condition on my vue file or the validation on text-field like `:maxlength='5'`.
- All I want is show the alert, if user input in the emp_code is letter, show `alert('Employee Code must be a number.')`, if user input in the emp_name is number, show `alert('Employee Name must be a letter.')`. If all fields are null, show `alert('You must input all the fields.')`.

Comment: Do you want to add validation on php side?

Comment: @Amini, yes i want to make the validation on php side. Although using alert in php is like `echo "<script>alert('Message here..')</script>"` i want it yo show on my vue file so i get trouble routing the alert from php to vue(vice versa)..

Comment: Is all on php side set up correctly?

Comment: Yes,,that's a working code. If click insert btn (all textfield in vue have value) it save on the database, if user don't input any data, their is error on console like `Cannot insert the value NULL into column...; column does not
allow nulls. INSERT fails.`..Tha'ts why i want a simple validation,*check input from vue to php then return alert if null, i want the validation came from php, not on vue.

Comment: I am aware of simple condtion like.. `If ($employee_code == null){ alert(' Please input Employee Code')else{
        DB::transaction(function() use($employee_data, $employee_code){
            Employee::insert(
                [
                    'EmployeeCode' => $employee_data["emp_code"],
                   //other codes here...
                ]
            );}` ,,But i dont know how to call this on the vue side.

Answer (score 0):

You can add **`rules`** attribute on **`v-text-field`** tag to control fading validation.

```
<v-text-field :rules="codeRules" dense outlined label="Employee Code" v-model="emp_code"></v-text-field>
<v-text-field :rules="nameRules" dense outlined label="Employee Name" v-model="emp_name"></v-text-field>
```

```
export default {
    data: () => ({
      firstName: '',
      codeRules: [
        value => {
          if (/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/.test(value)) return true
          return 'Employee Code must be a number.'
        },
      ],
      nameRules: [
        value => {
          if (/^[A-Za-z]+$/.test(value)) return true
          return 'Employee Name must be a letter.'
        },
      ],
    }),
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but i want the user to freely leave the textfield blank and show an alert box when texfield is empty and user click the insert button..

Answer (score 0):

This is already answered by my friend from other country after i reached him.
This is how he do it.

Giving this MVC Model Flow
[image]

Home.vue

```
<v-row dense>
                <v-col cols="2">
                    <v-text-field dense outlined label="Employee Code" v-model="myObj.EmployeeCode"></v-text-field>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="3">
                    <v-text-field dense outlined label="Employee Name" v-model="myObj.EmployeeName"></v-text-field>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="2">
                    <v-text-field dense outlined label="Age" v-model="myObj.Age"></v-text-field>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="2">
                    <v-btn @click="Insert()">INSERT</v-btn>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
```

mydata is...

```
data(){
            return {
                myObj:{
                    EmployeeCode: '',
                    EmployeeName: '',
                    Age: '',
                    EmployeeDeletedAt: '',
                }
```

Then, my method is...

```
 methods:{
        Insert(){
                axios.post(`api/employees`,this.myObj)
                .then(res => {
                    if(res.data instanceof Array){
                        console.log(res.data)
                        alert('Insert Successful!')
                    }else{
                        alert(res.data)
                    }
                }).catch(({response}) => {
                    this.$router.push('/error/' + response.status)
                })
            }
}
```

Controller.php

```
public function store(Request $req)
    {
        try {
            $employee_model = new EmployeeModel();
            $employee_model->InsertEmployee($req);
            return $employee_model->EmployeeList();
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            $err_data = ['Parameters' => $req, 'Functions' => __FUNCTION__];
            throw new CommonException($e, $err_data, 500);
        }
    }
```

Model.php

```
public function InsertEmployee($req){
        $dao_employee = new DAO();
        $existing = $dao_employee::ExistingEmployeeCode($req->input('EmployeeCode'));
        if($existing){
            return 'Existing Employee Code!';
        }else if(trim($req->input('EmployeeCode')) == ''){
            return 'Please input employee code!';
        }else if(trim($req->input('EmployeeName')) == ''){
            return 'Please input employee name!';
        }else if(trim($req->input('Age')) == ''){
            return 'Please input age!';
        }else if(strlen(trim($req->input('EmployeeCode'))) != 5){
            return 'Employee code must be 5 characters only';
        }else if(!is_numeric(trim($req->input('Age')))){
            return 'Age must be number only';
        }else{
            DB::transaction(function () use($req, $dao_employee){
                $dao_employee::InsertEmployee($req);
            });
        }
    }
```

DAO.php

```
public static function InsertEmployee($req){
        Employee::insert(
            [
                'EmployeeCode' => $req->input('EmployeeCode'),
                'EmployeeName' => $req->input('EmployeeName'),
                'Age' => (int)$req->input('Age'),
                'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'deleted_at' => null,
                'UpdatedBy' => '12345'
            ]
        );
    }
```

I hope this could help for future reference.