# Laravel cannot edit other information of user when using "exists()" in validation

Tags: php, laravel, vuetify.js

I have this field in my vue.

[image]

And this is what my edit view.
[image]

I have this validation to check if the user input or change his "Employee Code" that will exist on the database.

Controller.php

```
//Check if existing user.
public static function ExistingEmployeeCode($EmployeeCode){
  return Employee::where('EmployeeCode', $EmployeeCode)->exists();
}

//Validation for updating user.
public function UpdateEmployee($req){
  $employee = new Employee();
  $existing = $employee::ExistingEmployeeCode($req->input('EmployeeCode'));
  if($existing){
      return 'Existing Employee Code!';
  }else if(trim($req->input('EmployeeCode')) == ''){
      return 'Please input employee code!';
  }else if((trim($req->input('EmployeeName'))) == ''){
      return 'Please input employee name!';
  }else if((trim(!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]/",$req->input('EmployeeName'))))){
      return 'Employee Name must be letter only!';
  }else if(trim($req->input('Age')) == ''){
      return 'Please input age!';
  }else if(strlen(trim($req->input('EmployeeCode'))) != 5){
      return 'Employee code must be 5 characters only';
  }else if(!is_numeric(trim($req->input('Age')))){
      return 'Age must be number only';
  }else{
      DB::transaction(function () use($req, $employee){
          $employee::UpdateEmployee($req);
      });
      return employee::EmployeeList();
  }
}

//Query of my update
public static function UpdateEmployee($req){
Employee::where('EmployeeCode', $req->input('edit_id'))
->update(
    [
        'EmployeeCode' => (int)$req->input('EmployeeCode'),
        'EmployeeName' => $req->input('EmployeeName'),
        'Age' => (int)$req->input('Age'),
        'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'UpdatedBy' => 'admin',
    ]
);
```

All my funtion and queries are working well, But my problem is...
When i try to update/edit "EmployeeName" or it's employee "Age", the alert box will show this..

[image]

I know that the "ExistingEmployeeCode()" will cause this, But I'm currently learning laravel so I'm having trouble to create a separate validation if the user want to update only the employee name or employee age without removing the user exist validation, so i can use it when i add user that will have the same employee code.
※P.S. if user change its employee code, it will go(proceed/update) but still check if there is other user using that code(existing alert will show).

Thank you for understanding.

Comment: Where is the code that actually triggers and shows the call to `alert(...)`?

Comment: This is actually continuation of my work, you can refer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75830165/21370707) .My update function on my vue(methods)[here](https://i.imgur.com/YtUTNg3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Validation of Laravel https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation.

You should also learn about creating query by using Eloquent Model. You can reference https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent

They are so convenient.

However, if you persist to use this way. For checking existing employee code, you just ignore the employee who is being edited, like below:

```
//Validation for updating user.
public function UpdateEmployee($req){
  $employee = new Employee();
  if(trim($req->input('EmployeeCode')) != $req->input('edit_id') && $employee::ExistingEmployeeCode($req->input('EmployeeCode')){
      return 'Existing Employee Code!';
  }
  //….
}
```